# Error on woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this strange error on the WooCommerce checkout page. When I click on the pay button it gives me this weird error:

[image: woocommerce error on checkout page]

It was working well this morning. I updated WooCommerce to its latest version today,
but I also did a lot of other things like :

- Writing some codes to delete some shipping information for virtual products
- installing some plugins.
- Upgrading WooCommerce and installing Persian language and Rials currency for it

I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: I found the solution so i didn't check the stackoverflow for a few days , sorry

Comment: What was the solution @fanscode? I have the same issue!

Comment: You should change some codes in your payment plugin , Try changing 
get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_pay_page_id'))  to $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true );